# Recursion: Implement least recently used algorithm using a stack

Tags: c++, arrays, stack

I need some general advice about how to go about solving this question without over-complicating it any further:

> Using an array (and not a linked list), write a member function of the class StackType that updates the stack when a page is referenced.  Assuming a stack that can hold 5 values and the next page referenced is 7 then:
>
> - the function searches the stack for page 7
> - if it finds 7, removes it from stack and places it at the top
> - if is does not find 7 in the list, the last page referenced in the stack is removed and 7 places on top of the stack
>
> Use the following driver function:
>
> ```
> void updateRecursive(StackType<Type>& s, Type t);
> ```
>
> that calls the recursive function
>
> ```
> bool updateRecursiveDo(StackType<Type>& s, Type t);
> ```

What I have done so far and I will only include the relevant functions:

1. I've used the concept of an LRU algorithm to understand what is being asked here.
2. I understand that the only tools I really have at my disposal is push and pop.

RE: the driver function concept, I always understood this to be my main() program. i.e. the program that calls the function usually done in the case of testing but based on what they've provided me I looked up this detail in a textbook and found that a public driver function would be used to call a private recursive function to keep the no. of parameters in the public function to a minimum.

```
class StackType {
public: 
    void updateRecursive(StackType<Type>& s, Type t);
private:
    bool updateRecursiveDo(StackType<Type>& s, Type t);
}

template <class Type>
bool StackType<Type>::updateRecursiveDo(StackType<Type>& s, Type t) {
    if (isEmptyStack())
        return 0;
    else if(s.top() == t) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        s.pop();
        updateRecursiveDo(s,t);
    }
}

template <class Type>
void StackType<Type>::updateRecursive(StackType<Type>& s, Type t) {
    updateRecursiveDo(s,t);
}
```

So this is great, I call the function in main as follows and I've searched for the 7 and found it:

```
firstStack.updateRecursive(firstStack, 7);
```

Now what I'm doing is overthinking how to go about implementing the replacement of the numbers back onto the stack:

1. Store each item I pop into an array and iterate through each item then push them back onto the stack in each instance
2. Manually push the items back onto the stack but this wouldn't really work in the event that 7 didn't exist in the list

I am not sure if there is an easier way to deal with a search and replace when a stack is an array?

Comment: You should add a return statement in the `else` block of your `updateRecursiveDo` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several points of order:

1. I do not see any reason for your `updateRecursiveDo`() to return anything, be it a `bool`, or anything else. As I read your question, the purpose of `updateRecursiveDo`() is really to remove `t` from your stack, if it exists. Whether it exists, and this function removes it, or not, no longer matters at that point, because the only remaining step to be done would be to push the `t` value on top of the rebuilt stack.

And that step would occur whether or not `t` was found in the stack, so returning a `bool` indicator is irrelevant.

Furthermore, your implementation fails to return a `bool` value in the third case, so this wouldn't work anyway.

2. And your version of your `updateRecursiveDo()` doesn't do this correctly. Let's [explain what your function does to your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging):

   - if the stack is empty, don't do anything.
   - if the value on the top of the stack is `t` don't do anything.
   - otherwise remove the value from the top of the stack, and try again.

To that, your rubber duck would then ask the following logical question: "why are you removing everything on the stack, until you come to the value `t`, is that what you want to do?"

Of course not, based on the description you gave of your question. My interpretation of the three bullet points in your question is that only the value `t` should be removed from the stack, and not every value between the value `t`, and the end of the stack. Which could be the entire stack, if it doesn't contain the value `t`!

Now, how about you try explaining the following, instead, to your rubber duck:

- If the stack is empty, do nothing.
- Remove the value from the top of the stack.
- If the value is `t`, do nothing.
- Call itself recursively, and when the recursion call returns, push the value back on top of the current stack.

Translated into code, this would be:

```
template <class Type>
void StackType<Type>::updateRecursiveDo(StackType<Type>& s, Type t)
{
    if (isEmptyStack())    
        return;

    auto v=s.top();

    if (v == t)
        return;

    updateRecursiveDo(s, t);

    s.push(v);
    return;
}

template <class Type>
void StackType<Type>::updateRecursive(StackType<Type>& s, Type t)
{
    updateRecursiveDo(s, t);
    s.push(t);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Most insightful and the Rubber Duck debugging makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Think of `updateRecursiveDo()` as a method to delete an element from a stack. If the element is not found, remove the last one.

And after exit, push t to the top.

You're not replacing t but deleting it, then adding it again.

Use each recursive frame to temporally store the popped value in an internal variable, ie:

Pseudocode:

```
updateRecursiveDo(stackt stack, page t){
   x=stack.pop();
   if (x==t) return;
   if (stack.empty()) return;
   updateRecursiveDo(stack,t);
   stack.push(x);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. By doing this though I am popping each element off the stack and ultimately if I did find it and placed it back on top all the other elements I have popped off would no longer be there? Which is why I'm looking for a method where I don't lose these elements (which doesn't seem possible without popping them off and pushing them back onto the stack?)

Comment: Updated with example, you're right, thats how stacks work. Non recursive alternative is using a secondary stack.

Comment: Thanks for this. 2 things though. 1) I cannot assign s.pop() to a variable. I understand this is not possible from my research. Best I could do is assign s.top(). 2) If I don't pop() the stack before each recursive call I receive the error "Program received signal SIGSEVG, Segmentation fault" which to my understanding is due to my program trying to write to memory it shouldn't. So what I mean to say that is if I don't pop() the stack the recursive call will never end?

Comment: and also when I start out the stack is initialized with 5 values max so in order to push on more (besides a condition to end the recursive call) in order to push on more surely I would need to pop() at each recurrence?

Comment: Yes, with stl stack you do x=s.top() then s.pop(). You need to pop to reach the end condition.

Comment: Each time you call the recursion one element is removed, so you exit with max-1 elements.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your patience.